# How to check in which persistent store a managed object stored?

Tags: swift, core-data

My app uses core data to store data and it has multiple configurations: One configuration to sync with iCloud and other one for local data.

I did it by creating 2 NSPersistentStoreDescription, then assign them to the containter:

```
container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [cloud, local]
```

Those 2 persistent stores use the same model and entities.
If I want to add a managedObject to a store, I uses this code after inserting and before saving context.

```
assignObject:toPersistentStore:
```

Problem is in a list of all fetched objects in both stores, is there a way to know in which persistent store a specific managed object stored?

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who is interested: You can use this line to get persistent store or even configuration name:

```
managedObject.objectID.persistentStore?.configurationName
```

Many thanks to joro_estropia from reddit for this answer

Answer (score 0):

If you assign an entity to several configurations in your model file, the entity will be saved to all persistent stores whose descriptions have one of these configurations. In your case, both the local store and the cloud store  will store new objects.

**EDIT** (see comment):

I did not test this, but I believe it works this way:
You probably have a `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` that has a `persistentStoreCoordinator`. The coordinator can handle multiple stores, in your case a `local` store and an `iCloud` store that is mirrored to iCloud.
Since both configurations have the same entities, storing an entity stores it in both stores, the `iCloud` store change is uploaded to iCloud, and possibly synchronizes to other devices.
If now another device modifies the iCloud content, this is mirrored back to your app, and modifies only your `iCloud` store. It is now up to you to update your `local` store to make your database consistent.
This can be done by registering for `.NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange` notifications. If you receive one, you can update your `local` store accordingly.
Of course the whole process is error prone, as always if one stores the same information at different places.
So my suggestion is to store an entity only in one store.

Comment: Thank you for answering. So you meant even if I assign a managed object to local store, it will also be saved in cloud store, but not sync between devices?
Also, the managed object will be save in both local.sqlite and cloud.sqlite?